# Using Date for X axis in Gnuplot

Tags: date, gnuplot

I am trying to create a plot of internet speed against time, I have plotted the speed against data point, but I want to use the date for the X-axis the data is in the format

```
Wed 28 Sep 21:00:24 BST 2022 :   235.32  :    36.65
```

there are 24 data points per day, so ideally would just label each day, i.e. tics every 24 data points

I have got the line

```
set timefmt '"%a %d %b %H:%M:%S BST %Y"
```

to set the time format and then plotted the data using the command

```
plot "/home/indgepr/speedlog.txt" using 8 1 title "Download" axes x1y1 with linespoints ls 1
```

when run I get an error `; expected` ... any suggestions what I have done wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see several possible problems.

- There seems to be an extra leading quote mark in your timefmt line.  Just a typo in the question?
- In addition to defining a timefmt, you must also tell the program that the x axis uses time data: `set xdata time`.
- The plot command shown seems to be mangled.  As it stands `plot 'file' using 8 1 ...` tells it to take x coordinate data from column 8, and there is a dangling "1" that will confuse the program further.
- As shown, there is no reason to include `axes x1y1` or `ls 1`, since those are the default.  If there is a larger context that explains why you added these, please show the full command script. Otherwise I suggest removing them.

I think you want

```
set timefmt "%a %d %b %H:%M:%S BST %Y"
set xdata time
plot 'file' using 1:8 with linespoints title "Download"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunatly didn't quite work, no error but plotted all the points at one value on the X axis, I therefore added 'set xrange ["Thu 22 Sep 21:48:15 BST 2022":"Tue  4 Oct 20:00:28 BST 2022"]' and now get error "dataplot.gnu", line 38: Can't plot with an empty x range!

Comment: It is possible that the single line example you show does not correctly represent your actual data file.  Could you provide a longer chunk of test data or link to an actual data file?  For me that one line works after I cut-and-paste, but it may have lost tabs or other whitespace, and perhaps the next lines differ in some important way?